# Account Credit at Checkout

Tags: e-commerce, checkout, payment, accounts

What's the best user experience for applying account credit at checkout for an ecommerce store?

The current flow is that users have to apply a code per account credit voucher in a discount code field (and can only use one code per transaction!) which is a terrible experience.

I want to add in 'Account Credit' as a payment method, that when clicked displays the users account credit balance, with a toggle to apply all of their credit or a field to enter the amount they want to apply to their order.

But just wondering if there is a better way to be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You're right about typed-in voucher codes being a poor experience (though if that's how you've been operating, you might need to keep that available for a while after the redesign, lest any unentered credits be out there in the wild.)

If we assume that this goes away, and that account credits automatically show up on the payment screen at checkout in an aggregated amount, I think it's safe to bet that most users would want that to be their default payment option, unless there's a real reason to bank their credit for later use.

Amazon uses gift card balances as a default payment, and pairs them with the non-gift-card default method if the balance is insufficient. The user can click Change to change the payment method:

[image: Amazon gift card checkout screen]

If there's a reason to *not* default to using account credit (technical, accounting, or otherwise) you could borrow the pattern from "cash back bonus" credit cards and make a section below the standard payment selection area that allows the user to opt for the entire amount, or a partial amount:

[image: Discover card cashback]

It sounds like you might be on this track already. But I'd find out if it's really necessary to let the user have choice, here. What would be the benefit to the user of applying only $25 of a $50 credit to their order? Most businesses don't like to have a ton of account credit sitting around, as it creates liability on balance sheets. It might be best to just make your user apply their credits first before accepting additional (expensive) payment transactions.

Comment: yes to everything. Same principle (just not the same process since it's not a discount code) is used by Paypal: if you have money in your balance, they use the balance, otherwise they use your CC in account. This can apply to teh whole amount or just to cover the remaining amount needed to pay

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, what you are describing is a user wallet.

[image: Design mockup for wallet]

You want the wallet to be amongst the options of payment, but unlike the design mockup above, I don't think you want to make it a selectable option. Rather a compliment. So a more fitting design might have the wallet at the bottom with no styling to make it look like a button:

[image: wallet at the bottom]

But these are just ideas.